# Robocopy script to transfer user data from old PC to new PC

Tags: batch-file, cmd, transfer, robocopy, user-profile

I am trying to write a script that I can use to remotely transfer data from an end user's computer, to a new one I am preparing for them.  I will need to transfer data from multiple user profiles, so I have written it to cycle through the user profiles on the old machine, but I am unsure of the correct syntax in a couple places, specifically what variable I need to reference the current user folder as the script cycles through them (see the question marks in the directories listed below).

I wrote it to only copy user profiles that have been used in the last 90 days.  I would like to copy a few profiles such as Public, Default, etc regardless of age, but I will probably just add a few more Robocopy lines to accomplish that.

Can anyone advise me on what the syntax needs to be where the question marks appear below?  This would be $_ in Powershell, but I'm not sure what it is in a CMD batch file.

Thanks in advance,

Andrew

```
@echo off

Set /p OldPC=Please enter the old PC name:
Set /p NewPC=Please enter the new PC name:

for /D %%D in ("\\%OldPC%\USERS\*") do (robocopy "\\%OldPC%\USERS\?\Desktop" "\\%NewPC%\Users\?\Desktop" /E /Z /W:10 /COPYALL /MAXAGE:90
for /D %%D in ("\\%OldPC%\USERS\*") do (robocopy "\\%OldPC%\USERS\?\Documents" "\\%NewPC%\Users\?\Documents" /E /Z /W:10 /COPYALL /MAXAGE:90
for /D %%D in ("\\%OldPC%\USERS\*") do (robocopy "\\%OldPC%\USERS\?\Favorites" "\\%NewPC%\Users\?\Favorites" /E /Z /W:10 /COPYALL /MAXAGE:90
for /D %%D in ("\\%OldPC%\USERS\*") do (robocopy "\\%OldPC%\USERS\?\Pictures" "\\%NewPC%\Users\?\Pictures" /E /Z /W:10 /COPYALL /MAXAGE:90
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you needed more than what you asked.

From what I understood, you want to copy user profile folders for the users who have been using the computer since some date.

To solve the problem, it would be better to find users who logged on rather than finding any file that is edited. Finding edited files will consume too much time to just find the names of used user accounts.

Since there is `wevtutil` command that is used to deal with logged events, the code became quite simpler.

So the code looks like this:

```
@echo off
pushd %~dp0
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

::User Input
set /p OldPC=Please enter the old PC name: 
set /p NewPC=Please enter the new PC name: 
set /p UserName=Please enter the User name to use in %OldPC%: 
set /p Password=Please enter the password to use in %OldPC%: 
set /p MaxDate=Please enter the Maximum logon date: 
cls


echo Deriving User Names that are used since %MaxDate%...
echo If this step takes too long, check if you typed correct user name and password.

wevtutil qe Security /r:%OldPC% /u:%UserName% /p:%Password% /f:text /q:"*[System[TimeCreated[@SystemTime>='%MaxDate%T00:00:00'] and (EventID=4624)]]" |^
findstr /b /c:" Account Name" >PossibleUserName.tmp1
dir /b "\\%OldPC%\Users" >UserProfileList.tmp1
findstr /g:"UserProfileList.tmp1" "PossibleUserName.tmp1"|sort >UserList.tmp2
del /q *.tmp1

cls
echo Formatting User List...

for /f "tokens=2 delims=:   " %%a in (UserList.tmp2) do (
    if not "!ln!"=="%%a" (
        set "ln=%%a"
        echo %%a>>FinalList.tmp
    )
)
del /q *.tmp2

cls
echo Copying Files...

for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (FinalList.tmp) do (
    echo robocopy "\\%OldPC%\Users\%%a\Desktop" "\\%NewPC%\Users\%%a\Desktop" /e /z /w:10 /copyall
    echo robocopy "\\%OldPC%\Users\%%a\Documents" "\\%NewPC%\Users\%%a\Documents" /e /z /w:10 /copyall
    echo robocopy "\\%OldPC%\Users\%%a\Favorites" "\\%NewPC%\Users\%%a\Favorites" /e /z /w:10 /copyall
    echo robocopy "\\%OldPC%\Users\%%a\Pictures" "\\%NewPC%\Users\%%a\Pictures" /e /z /w:10 /copyall
)

echo Done!
del /q *.tmp
pause>nul
exit
```

Since you are trying to use the script from the remote computer, `wevtutil` command required log in information for your old PC.

Also, you need to input the date that you want to use in `%MaxDate%`, which will enable you to filter the logs since that date.
The date format should look like this: **YYYY-MM-DD**

For example, you should type ***2017-01-01*** if you want to filter users who used the computer since ***January 1, 2017***.

If you set both old and new computers to share their `Users` Directories with correct properties, then you would be good to go with this code.

I hope this code would solve your problem.

Comment: Great, thanks for the info.  I realized that I have something written wrong as well... I want to completely skip any user profile that has a modified date more than 90 days old, but I want to copy all contents of the folders listed for any profile that is more recent than that.  The way I have it written, I think it will copy from all user folders, but skip any contents that is more than 90 days old.  Am I correct?  I'm guessing I maybe need an IF statement someplace?

Comment: Here's another thought...  would it be easier to just Robocopy the entire C:\Users directory with the /MAXAGE switch, and then /XD to exclude profile folders I don't want, such as appdata, etc?

Comment: @Andrew To make things cleared, are you trying to move the entire user profile directory if one of its file is modified within 90 days?

Comment: You should use `%%~nxD` instead in case a folder name contains a `.`; instead of `\\%OldPC%\USERS\%%~nD`, you could also simply use `%%~D` or `%%~fD`...

Comment: If I were to copy the data manually, I would browse out to C:\Users, sort by modified date, and copy all user profiles that have a modified date within 90 days, thus copying data from all users that still use the workstation periodically, and skipping those that don't.  I am trying to accomplish the same with the script, with the added benefit of only copying the Desktop, Documents, Favorites, and Pictures folders from each user profile, thus making the transfer faster by skipping AppData, etc.  Does that answer your question?

Comment: @Andrew I edited code. It is not fully tested yet, so test it first and than remove `echo` command that is located in front of `Robocopy` command to actually copy the files. Run the script as Admin.

Comment: Thanks much, this is looking really good.  One more thing I haven't specified yet, is I usually run this from an external drive (F:) on my computer.  Is the batch file assumed to be run from the C: drive?  And can it be run from any computer, or does it want to be run from the old or new computer in it's current state?  The first time I ran it, it had trouble finding FinalList.tmp, and could not find F:\*.tmp at the end, which makes sense if the script thinks it's on the C: drive.

Comment: @Andrew You can run the script in your external drive. Since I fixed the error of the script, it would be fine now to use.

Comment: This still doesn't seem to be working.  You originally mentioned setting up shared user directories, which I haven't done as this is being run in a domain environment and I have administrative credentials.  Does this method conflict with how it's written?

Comment: @Andrew Look this page to setup for folder sharing. [link](http://www.howtogeek.com/school/windows-network-sharing/lesson7/all/) You need to share your user profiles with their own names. For example, if there is a profile located in "C:\Users\User1", then you need to share this folder with name "User1"